# How to build h5py with MPI support (against Parallel HDF5) on Linux, 2023

Tags: python, mpi, hdf5, h5py

I'm reproducing a deep-learning model on a linux server, which uses h5py to process data.

Following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line ..., in ...
    fdest = h5py.File(dest, "a", driver="mpio", comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\Lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 558, in __init__
    fapl = make_fapl(driver, libver, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\Lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 177, in make_fapl
    set_fapl(plist, **kwds)
  File "...\Lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 53, in _set_fapl_mpio
    raise ValueError("h5py was built without MPI support, can't use mpio driver")
ValueError: h5py was built without MPI support, can't use mpio driver
```

This means my h5py **was built without MPI support**.

However, [official document](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/mpi.html#building-against-parallel-hdf5) doesn't give a clear instruction of **how to build h5py with MPI support**.

So the question is, how to build h5py with MPI support (against Parallel HDF5) on Linux, 2023.

Answer (score 1):

## My method should both work on Ubuntu and RedHat without super user permission

### 0. Preparation

1. gcc, as a build essential
2. anaconda or miniconda

### 1. Install open-mpi

Go to [official website](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/) of openmpi releases.

Download the lastest release (ended with ".tar.gz").

Open the terminal and change dir to the download destination, which in my case, I should run:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Suppose the pack's name is "openmpi-4.1.5.tar.gz".

Run following command to extract the package:

```
tar xvzf openmpi-4.1.5.tar.gz
```

You will get a folder named "openmpi-4.1.5" under the current dir.
Remember the path of the folder.
We will get back here when testing.

In terminal, change dir into the folder.

Run following command to configure:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/username/openmpi
```

Run following command to install:

```
sudo make all install
```

Run following command to open .bashrc (If you do not want to use vim, use another text editor such as `nano` or `gredit` instead.):

```
sudo vim ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following line to the bottom of .bashrc:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/username/openmpi/lib
```

Run following command to activate changes immediately:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Change terminal dir to the example folder of the previous extracted folder.
In my case, I should run following command:

```
cd ~/Downloads/openmpi-4.1.5/examples
```

Run following command to build:

```
make
```

Run following command to run test file

```
mpirun -np 4 hello_c
```

If the ouput is 4 lines of "Hello World", then you have successfully installed open-mpi.

### 2. Install HDF5

Go to [official website](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/source-code) of HDF5 to download the latest release of HDF5 (which in my case is hdf5-1.14.2.tar.gz)

Open ternimal. Change dir to the download destination.

Run following code to extract:

```
tar xvzf hdf5-1.14.2.tar.gz
```

Change dir into the extracted folder.

Run following code to set MPI-C as compiler:

```
export CC=mpicc
```

Run following code to turn on HDF5_MPI:

```
export HDF5_MPI="ON"
```

Run following code to change build config:

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-parallel --prefix=/home/username/hdf5
```

Run following code to set default HDF5_dir:

```
export HDF5_DIR="/home/username/hdf5"
```

Run following code to compile:

```
make
```

Run following code to install HDF5:

```
make install
```

Run following code to install some other things (Sry. I'm not sure what "other things" are.):

```
make check-install
```

### 3. Install h5py with MPI and HDF5 build

Create and activate a new env.

```
conda create -n NewEnv
conda activate NewEnv
```

Run following command to install openmpi in the env:

```
conda install openmpi
```

Install tree additional packages:

```
conda install gcc_linux-64
conda install gxx_linux-64
conda install gfortran_linux-64
```

Run following command to set MPI-C as compiler:

```
export CC=mpicc
```

Run following command to turn on HDF5_MPI:

```
export HDF5_MPI="ON"
```

Run following command to set default HDF5_dir:

```
export HDF5_DIR="/home/username/hdf5"
```

Run following command to build h5py from source:

```
pip install --no-binary=h5py h5py
```

Okay. Now you should have successfully built h5py with MPI support (against Parallel HDF5).